# Add line break to git diff --name-only

Tags: git

name-only and saving the output to a file.
but the changed file names are on same line. Can i put one changed file name in one line

```
git diff HEAD~3 --name-only > ../name.txt
```

example output:

```
a.jsb.jsc.js
```

expected

```
a.js
b.js
c.js
```

I am using windows 10 OS and CMD

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
credential.helper=manager
difftool.usebuiltin=true
gui.recentrepo=C:/My Data/Frontend Development/my projects/ain
gui.recentrepo=C:/NovCR
alias.gl=git
core.autocrlf=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
svn-remote.svn.url=https://abcd.ko.com/svn/a/b
svn-remote.svn.fetch=:refs/remotes/git-svn
```

Comment: What OS, shell and git version are you using? I just tested it in Windows, CMD or git bash, and the line breaks are still there.

Comment: windows 10. I have updated the question.Using CMD

Comment: On linux line breaks are there as expected. Are you sure there are no line breaks? Or is it just something like \n vs \r\n?

Comment: On Console I can see one file on oneline but not in the file I save the output to. I tried autocrlf to true, it didnt work. There are no  '\r\n' in output file....the output is exactly like the "exampleoutput" pasted in question

Comment: CMD it works, with Git 2.11

Comment: git version 2.10.1.windows.1 came with visual studio enterprise edition 2015

Comment: May be a config issue: what git config -l returns?

Comment: Hi I updated git to 2.11 still not working. Pasted config in question

Comment: "On Console I can see one file on oneline but not in the file I save the output to." - - what are you using to look at the file?

Comment: Regular windows notepad

Comment: [Hmmm](https://www.google.com/search?q=does+windows+notepad+display+newlines+properly).

Comment: Thanks @jthill . Sorry for silly mistake. Notepad will not show newline

Answer (score 0):

This is a CRLF vs LF end of line issue.  I had the same problem when opening the git diff redirected output file in Notepad (which needs CRLF to show on a new line).  When I opened the output in Notepad++ it was on separate lines (Notepad++ can read/display unix style line feed formatted files).